# Focus on the first edtitext in android

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have four edittexts the problem is when i start activity the focus will be on the last edittext , how can i make the focus on the first edittext using xml ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**onCreate();** of Activity

```
EditText firsteditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
EditText secondeditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.second);
EditText thirdeditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.third);
EditText fourtheditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fourth);

     firsteditText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: is there any way using xml file

Comment: too large , can you tell me is there a property to set the focus on specific edittext

Comment: i think that you have to put "tag" <edittext> in sequencing manner, then may be it support what you want
try to declare <EditText1></<EditText1> <EditText2></<EditText2> <EditText3></<EditText3> and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [requestFocus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#requestfocus-element) element.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add a `<requestFocus/>` tab in the activity xml.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 2.3.3, you can click on the focusedByDefault attribute in the Properties panel on the EditText you want the focus on first.